# Spring when to use in memory authentication

Tags: spring, authentication

I'm a completely newbie with Spring and I'm learning how to implement authentication.

One thing that confuses me now is the in memory authentication.

My understanding of authentication flow should be something like this:

1. user make a request with user name and password
2. spring framework should authenticate with the user table in database.

I might be completely wrong about this so please correct me. And till now I keep seeing examples of in-memory authentication which does not quite make sense to me.

1. what is in memory authentication, why is it needed? I have tried to googled that around but no one seems to think that's a question.
2. all examples I have seen so far had hard coded user name and passwords. how is this going to work in a real world with thousthands of users?
3. When should we use in memory authentication?

Comment: That one is mainly used for teaching purpose. Always is easier create a couple of in-memory users to explain how the security works but, as you mentioned, in a real scenario those ones should be managed from a "non-temporary" storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in Spring Security you need to provide implementation of this interface:

```
public interface UserDetailsService {
    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String var1) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
}
```

Where UserDetails looks like this:

```
public interface UserDetails extends Serializable {
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();

    String getPassword();

    String getUsername();

    boolean isAccountNonExpired();

    boolean isAccountNonLocked();

    boolean isCredentialsNonExpired();

    boolean isEnabled();
```

}

UserDetailsService should be a service which spring security uses to find username of type UserDetails (it happens after you provide login and password and start authentication). You can provide implementation which will be calling your database but you can also provide implementation which will be checking if user with provided username exists in some HashMap for example.

1. So in-memory auth is a situation where you provide implementation of UserDetailsService which doesn't call db but just checks some in memory map for example.
2. Such examples are just for simplicity so no one uses such config in prod (at least that doesn't make too much sense).
3. In my opinion only for some proof of concepts or real small/specific projects.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, could you provide a tutorial for the UserDetailsService example. I'm trying to do things the proper way but I found it a bit hard to find the UserDetailsService approach.

Comment: Here https://github.com/slabiak/AppointmentScheduler/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/example/slabiak/appointmentscheduler/security you can see spring security config of real world project. Here is a short tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database For more details I suggest looking at spring's docs.

Answer (score -3):

In-memory authentication refers to a method of authenticating users in computer systems where the authentication information is stored in memory rather than being retrieved from a persistent data store, such as a database, every time authentication is needed.

Traditional authentication systems often involve querying a database to check if a user's credentials (such as username and password) are valid. In contrast, in-memory authentication keeps a copy of the authentication data in the system's memory, making the authentication process faster and more efficient.

Here are some key points about in-memory authentication:

Performance: Storing authentication data in memory reduces the need for repeated database queries, leading to faster authentication processes. This is particularly beneficial in systems with high user traffic or where low latency is critical.

Caching: In-memory authentication can be seen as a form of caching, where the authentication data is temporarily stored in memory for quicker access. This can help improve overall system performance and responsiveness.

Session Management: In-memory authentication is often used in conjunction with session management. Once a user is authenticated, their session information is stored in memory, allowing for quick and efficient access to the user's authentication status during subsequent interactions.

Statelessness: In-memory authentication can contribute to creating stateless systems, where each request from a client to a server contains all the information needed to understand and fulfill the request. This can simplify system architecture and scalability.

Security Considerations: While in-memory authentication can improve performance, it's essential to consider security implications. Storing sensitive authentication data in memory requires appropriate safeguards to prevent unauthorized access. Additionally, if the in-memory data is not periodically synchronized with a secure data store, there could be a risk of data inconsistency.

In-memory authentication is commonly used in web applications, APIs, and other systems where rapid and frequent user authentication is required. It is often part of broader authentication and authorization mechanisms that ensure secure access to resources while optimizing performance.

Comment: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541)